If a collection of bounded linear operators and uniformly unbounded then there is a dense subset of the Banach space on which this happens.
Let $ (X, \|\cdot\|) $ be a Banach space and $ (Y, \|\cdot\|) $ be a normed linear space. Suppose $ \mathcal{A} \subset B(X, Y) $ is not uniformly bounded. Prove that there exists a dense subset $ D \subset X $ such that for all $ x \in D $, the set $ \{ A(x) \mid A \in \mathcal{A} \} $ is unbounded.
Let $ S $ be the set of all points $ x \in X $ such that the set $ \{ A(x) \mid A \in \mathcal{A} \} $ is unbounded. Suppose $ S $ is not dense in $ X $. Then there exists $ x_0 \in X $ and $ r > 0 $ such that the ball $ B(x_0, r) \cap \overline{S} = \emptyset $.
If the set $ \{ A(x) \mid A \in \mathcal{A} \} $ is bounded for all $ x $ in some non-empty open set $ B(x_0, r) \subset X \setminus \overline{S} $, then the operators $ A \in \mathcal{A} $ would be uniformly bounded in this set.
Can't proceed from here, can someone help? Initially I thought of applying PUB.

Take a look at the bottom of the corollaries section of the Wikipedia page on the PUB. In brief the proof given there of the PUB shows that for each $n$ the set ${,x\in X:\sup_{A\in\mathcal A}\lVert A(x)\rVert>n,}$ is dense.

Observe that any proper subspace $Y\subset X$ has dense complement. Indeed, if a subspace $Y\subset X$ does not have dense complement, then it contains a ball, say $B(x;r)$, then, by translating, it also contains the ball $B(\mathbf{0}; r)$ and by scaling we see that $Y=X$.
Returning to your question, let us show the contrapositive. So assume that for all dense subsets $D\subset X$, there is an $x\in D$ such that $\{Ax \mid A\in \mathcal{A}\}$ is bounded. Now consider the subspace
$$Y=\{x\in X \mid \{Ax \mid A\in \mathcal{A}\} \text{ is bounded}\}.$$
Our assumption gives that $Y$ intersects any dense subset of $X$. By our initial observation, $Y$ cannot be proper, so we must have $Y=X$. In other words, $\mathcal{A}$ is pointwise bounded and the Principle of Uniform Boundedness gives that $\mathcal{A}$ is uniformly bounded.
